# Grab IDs of all elements in DOM tree order on Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm building a form on a page that has a drag-and-drop interface with [jQuery UI's sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/), and it's being integrated in to [Bootstrap 3's JavaScript Tabs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs). However, once the content is in the order I want it, and the form is submitted, I need to "loop through" all the relevant elements and submit them, in the DOM tree order, for a script to handle.

My form's structure is as follows:

```
<form>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane" id="ASF">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <ul class="list-group connected" id="8-1">
                <li class="list-group-item ui-state-default-ui-state-disabled ui-state-locked">Day 1</li>
                <li class="list-group-item ui-state-default" id="27275"></li>
                <li class="list-group-item ui-state-default" id="27213"></li>
                ...
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <ul class="list-group connected" id="8-2">
                <li class="list-group-item ui-state-default-ui-state-disabled ui-state-locked">Day 2</li>
                <li class="list-group-item ui-state-default" id="28445"></li>
                <li class="list-group-item ui-state-default" id="26784"></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            ...
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="CSPE">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <ul class="list-group connected" id="20-1">
                <li class="list-group-item ui-state-default-ui-state-disabled ui-state-locked">Day 1</li>
                <li class="list-group-item ui-state-default" id="18775"></li>
                <li class="list-group-item ui-state-default" id="36225"></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-4">
              <ul class="list-group connected" id="20-2">
                <li class="list-group-item ui-state-default-ui-state-disabled ui-state-locked">Day 2</li>
                <li class="list-group-item ui-state-default" id="84451"></li>
                <li class="list-group-item ui-state-default" id="78955"></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
  <input type="hidden" name="data_array[]">
  <button class="btn-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now, when the form is submitted, I need to POST through the IDs of *all* the elements that **have** IDs via the input `data_array`, correctly nested how they are on the page at this moment. i.e.:

```
array(
  "ASF" => array(
    "8-1" => array(
      "27275", "27213"
    ),
    "8-2" => array(
      "28445", "26784"
    )
  ),
  "CSPE" => array(
    "20-1" => array(
      "18775", "36225"
    ),
    "20-2" => array(
      "84451", "78955"
    ),
  )
)
```

However, I'm not really sure where to start! Researching makes me think I need to use `.each()` to loop through the elements on a page, and possible `.find()` to find elements nested within others, but how to even tackle this problem is completely beyond my expertise.

Or is there possibly an easier way to do the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery's hasAttribute selector on an each loop:

```
$("*[id]").each(function( index ) {

});
```

https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/